# Run a powershell on a remote machine using JAVA

Tags: java, powershell

I want to run a powershell in some remote machine using java.
    How can this be achieved.?
currently this code is not running the powershell command locally.!!

```
  public void main() throws Exception{

  String[] command = { /*"cmd.exe", "/C",*/ "powershell", "Command","&","echo '********** hello world ********'"};
  String out;

  ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);

  Process process = null;

  try {
                            process = processBuilder.start();
                             Logger.getInstance().info("process started" );

                        } catch (IOException e2) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e2.printStackTrace();
                        }


                        java.io.InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
                        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                        // create a reader for the return data from cmd.
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        // create a string builder to automate the string addition

                        try {
                            while ((out = br.readLine()) != null) {// build the input
                                                                        // string from
                                                                        // cmd.

                                sb = sb.append(out);
                    System.out.println(out);

                            }


                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

this code runs for indefinite time. without any output.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to run something like "invoke-command -computername Server1 -filepath c:\scripts\script.ps1"

```
    Process p = new ProcessBuilder()
            .inheritIO()
            .command("invoke-command", "-computername", "Server1",
                    "-filepath", "C:\\scripts\\script.ps1").start();
    p.waitFor();
```

but first of all make sure that this command work OK from command line.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this via java method.?

Comment: Currently I am juss trying to run a powershell command locally

Comment: Please see my edit and let me know what went wrong in the code. which will run a powershell command locally.

Comment: new ProcessBuilder().inheritIO().command("powershell", "echo", "111").start(); works OK for me and prints 111,try it

Comment: cannot resolve importIO(), which import did you use. I have used import.java.io.*

Comment: Can you please share the complete working code, which will run an echo command in powershell.