# Run remote power shell script using java

Tags: java, linux, powershell, exec, apache-camel

using java i am trying to execute a remote power shell script with some arguments from my linux box.
please help.

Apache Camel has "exec" component to call script but how can i call remote power shell script from there ...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152360/run-a-powershell-on-a-remote-machine-using-java

Comment: If you can find the command which can work in linux, then you just setup the uri which exec://COMMAND with some other argument.